# How to generate tuples with some constant values with comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to generate tuples with some constant values with comprehension?

I would like to have something like

```
[
(0, 'A', 'B'),
(1, 'A', 'B'),
(2, 'A', 'B'),
(3, 'A', 'B'),
...
]
```

so I would take `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` from range. But how to get `A`s and `B`s, which are not change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not because tuples are immutable that you cannot generate a list of tuples with a variable item only:

```
result = [(i,'A','B') for i in range(1,5)]

print(result)
```

yields:

```
[(1, 'A', 'B'), (2, 'A', 'B'), (3, 'A', 'B'), (4, 'A', 'B')]
```